# C# fire event after return statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `Log` method which creates a `LogMessage` object, and fires an event `OnMessage`

The method returns the `LogMessage` object after the `event` has been invoked.

Is it possible to *delay* the event, so it occurs after the return statement?

The reason i need this, is because i want to be able to alter the `LogMessage` object before the event will raise.

```
public class Logger
{
    public static event LogMessageCreatedEventHandler OnMessage;

    public LogMessage Log(string logLevel, string message)
    {
        LogMessage logMessage = new LogMessage
        {
            Message = message,
            LogLevel = logLevel,
            DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow
        };

        OnMessage?.Invoke(this, new LogMessageCreatedEventArgs { LogMessage = logMessage });

        return logMessage;
    }
}


// usage

var logMessage = _logger.Log("Debug", "Product has been created");  <-- the event is invoked now
logMessage.CustomProp.Add("isProductsService", true);               <-- this property is not available in the Event Handler
```

One idea would be to use `Task.Delay()`, but i don't think this is a good solution.

```
Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(_ => {
    OnMessage?.Invoke(this, new LogMessageCreatedEventArgs { LogMessage = logMessage });
});

return message;
```

Comment: This is very strange solution. If you need to alter `LogMessage`, return the copy.

Comment: If you need to add aditional properties to your message, include them in the original Log() call by just adding a method override.

Comment: Do you mean to return the copy from the Event Handler? no, the Event Handler needs to have the "final" version with the updated properties already

Comment: @PMF, yes, you are right. I want to avoid this if possible, my code is simplified, and it already has enough arguments to the method.

Comment: Why is your event handler `static`? If it were non-static, you could trivially add an event handler yourself to modify the event args. So long as your event handler would be first, other subscribers would see your modified version.

Comment: @hvd Unfortunately the code usage must be as in the example above. The event is static because i subscribe to it in `Application_Start`, and based on those `CustomProp` values i need to save the message in different locations. There is only one `Logger` instance in the app

Comment: Pass 'Action<LogMessage>' callback to Log, so that caller can apply required modifications before you fire the event.

Comment: @Evk i wanted to avoid adding a new argument to the method, but it seems that this is the only viable solution. `dasblinkenlight` suggested this in his answer, so i'm going to accept it, but you can post an answer and i will vote it :)

Comment: Well accepted answer is similar but not the same - I suggest local callback, not global one.

Comment: @Evk With local, yes, global won't help with my scenario.

Comment: It the argument to not pass an `Action<LogMessage>` as @Evk suggested is that there are already too many arguments to the Log method you might consider one or more overloads of the `Log` method to facilitate different scenario's for creating logmessages. Or create a LogMessage factory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Task.Delay(1000)` creates a race condition. Delaying the event till after the `return` is insufficient, because the caller may or may not have enough time to complete its modifications to `LogMessage` in time for the event to pick up modified properties.

One way to make sure that modifications are over before the event is fired is to plug a piece of code in between of creating the event and firing it. This can be done with a delegate:

```
public static event LogMessageCreatedEventHandler OnMessage;
// By default message preprocessor does nothing
public static Func<LogMessage,LogMessage> Preprocess { get; set; } = m => m;

public LogMessage Log(string logLevel, string message) {
    LogMessage logMessage = new LogMessage {
        Message = message,
        LogLevel = logLevel,
        DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow
    };
    OnMessage?.Invoke(this, new LogMessageCreatedEventArgs {
        LogMessage = Preprocess(logMessage)
    });
    return logMessage;
}
```

Now you can add preprocessing logic to `Logger` to make modifications to `LogMessage`:

```
Logger.Preprocessor = lm => {
    lm.PropertyToBeChanged = newPropertyValue;
    lm.AnotherProperty = someOtherValue;
    return lm;
};
```

> I need to update the property at "contextual" level, rather than on Global level, where I lose the information from where the log message was created.

You can pass the `Func` as a parameter to `Log`, as follows:

```
private static readonly Func<LogMessage,LogMessage> doNothing = m => m;
public LogMessage Log(string logLevel, string message, Func<LogMessage,LogMessage> preprocess = doNothing) {
    LogMessage logMessage = new LogMessage {
        Message = message,
        LogLevel = logLevel,
        DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow
    };
    OnMessage?.Invoke(this, new LogMessageCreatedEventArgs {
        LogMessage = preprocess(logMessage)
    });
    return logMessage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. While this works, is not the desired approach, because i need to update the property at "contextual" level, rather than on Global level, where i lose the information from where the log message was created.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but it seems like it's the only reliable solution. Thank you